# Window functions and indexes larger than N/2

Tags: window-functions, c

How does the n index for a window with $0 \le |n| \le N/2$ e.g the Bohman window function, get implemented when having a specific window size?

[image]

```
if (n >= 0 && n <= N/2)
```

what happens with the passed in index e.g. 1000 of a 1024 window size ?

Answer (score 1):

The window is defined as $-N/2 \le n \le N/2$ i.e. symmetric about $n=0$.

So, for a 1024 window size, $n=-512$ to $n=+511$ should give you the appropriate coefficients.

Comment: Thanks. So why doesnt the range indicate the -N/2, but starts from 0 instead?

Comment: @Helium3 It says $0 \le | n | \le N/2$, so $n$ can be negative.

Answer (score 1):

If you subtract N/2 from n in the equation, then your window will be centered at N/2, and n can range from 0 to N (e.g. larger than N/2).

Comment: ah, that makes sense, hence the | n |. Thanks!

Comment: just to clarify, so the index will become a float? e.g. double bohman(int i, int N) {
    float index = i - N/2;
    double f = fabs(index)/(N/2);
    return (1 - f) * cos(M_PI * f) + 1/M_PI * sin(M_PI * f);
}